# Область видимости $_SESSION

Tags: php

Есть файл `user.php` где я работаю с переменной `$_SESSION`.
Он подключен к `index.php` но переменная нигде не определяется кроме `user.php`.
Что надо сделать, чтоб переменная и ее индексы были видны в любом из трех файлов?

**index.php**:

```
<?php
    include "cfg.php"; //Тут лежит функция session_start();
    include "user.php"; //Операции с $_SESSION
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Это 'суперглобальная' или автоматическая глобальная переменная. Это
>   просто означает что она доступна во всех контекстах скрипта. Нет
>   необходимости выполнять global $variable; для доступа к ней внутри
>   метода или функции.

[PHP:$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php)

То есть $_SESSION доступен везде

Comment: Но у меня проблемы с досутоп к этой переменной из разных файлов. Я пишу что то в $_SESSION в одном файле, но мне досутпны действия с нужными индексами в другом... В выше указанном примере кода, мне не досупны индексы переменнной в index.php . В чем может быть причина?

Comment: @AlexanderRyabikov пробовали в index.php выполнить `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: Там отсутствовали какие либо индексы